# Re-assigning Instance Variables to Local Method Variables

Tags: python, class, namespaces

I have seen the following many times, where the instance variables (ex. `obj_foo` and `obj_bar`) are re-assigned to be local method variables (ex. within `call`):

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, obj_foo, obj_bar):
        self.obj_foo = obj_foo
        self.obj_bar = obj_bar

    def call(self):
        obj_foo, obj_bar = self.obj_foo, self.obj_bar

        obj_foo.do_something()
        obj_bar.do_something_else()
```

I am not sure if this is convention (easy to read) or if there is a more significant purpose?

Is this bad practice?

Does this effect performance?

Comment: probably is just to avoid using `self.` before the varaibles names, because both variables will be referencing the same objects

Comment: As for good or bad, there may be some justification for micro-optimizations in fairly extreme cases. But if its just to make it look more like C++ or to avoid writer's cramp, its a bad idea. First, its unclear that you are referring to an instance object, and second, if it is reassigned (`obj_foo = other_thing`) its also unclear whether the writer intended this to be local only or whether its a bug. This reduces maintainability, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, there is no reason to do that, but in some circumstances it may be:

- faster (because access to local variables is fast)
- more easily readable (because it is shorter)

The speed is probably the more important factor here. Accessing member variables involves various mechanisms (see [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)) which take some time to resolve. Additionally, the getter for the variable may do something even more expensive.

On the other hand, local variables are in CPython optimised at compile time, so there is actually no lookup for a variable named `'obj_foo'` in the `__dict__`, but instead the interpreter just picks the first local variable, because it knows that `obj_foo` is the first local variable without the need to search for the name.

So, if a member variable is used many times in the same function and profiling shows that it takes significant time to access that member variable, it may be useful to use a local variable instead.

---

Usually, that does not make a big difference, but here is an example to show the idea:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

    def f(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.x()

class B:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

    def f(self):
        x=self.x
        for i in range(100):
            x()
```

The timing is almost the same, but there is some difference:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a.f()', setup='a=A(lambda:None)', globals=locals())
13.119033042000638
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('b.f()', setup='b=B(lambda:None)', globals=locals())
10.219889547632562
```

IMHO, in this case, the difference is barely enough to justify adding that one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this just to avoid writing out `self` every time.

However, it could also be that there is a more important reason to do this: it could completely change the semantics. Example:

```
def __init__(self, x):
  self.x = 42

def theMethod(self):
  x = self.x
  self.x = 58
  print(x)
  print(self.x)
```

In this example, `x` and `self.x` are not interchangeable, even though you have assigned `x = self.x` in the first line of `theMethod`. The first `print` will output `42`, the second `print` will output `58`. This can happen every time that some member variable is assigned to a local variable and then overridden.

How this impacts performance is not entirely obvious, because both lookups `self.x` and `x` will have to look for the symbol in a dictionary: in the first case, the dictionary of the member variables of `self`, in the second case, in the current scope. It could impact the performance both positively *and* negatively, depending on how many and what other variables are defined in each scope. In most non-contrived cases, it *could* have a tiny positive effect on performance.

**EDIT:** As @zvone has pointed out, the last paragraph does not necessarily hold for all implementations of the python interpreter.

Comment: Hi Andrey. Can you please elaborate on why this may work for certain implementations of the interpreter but not others?

Comment: In CPython, this is a common micro-optimization, because local variable namespaces are optimized to a primitive array instead instead of a `dict` and can be accessed much faster.

Comment: @Scott zvone's answer explains it quite nicely: apparently, CPython performs some special optimizations for local variables, so no dictionary lookup is necessary when accessing the value of a local variable. This could be much faster than looking it up in the `__dict__` of the object. The paragraph about the changed semantics still holds, though.

Comment: Note, this is the primary reason for the introduction of `__slots__`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I guess I was confused as to the part about different "implementations of the python interpreter"? Not all python interpeters handle local variable access the same way?